# Room migration test fails due to missing FTS rowid column

Tags: android, sql, android-room, database-migration

I'm using FTS4 with Room with these two entities:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "persons")
data class Person(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "employed") val employed: Boolean)

@Fts4(contentEntity = Person::class)
@Entity(tableName = "persons_fts")
data class PersonFts(
        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")val rowid: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String)
```

Now let's say that because of the current crisis, everyone lost their jobs and the `employed` column is no longer needed because nobody is employed. I want to migrate my database by removing that column. Here's the migration statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons_temp (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO persons_temp (id, name) SELECT id, name FROM persons
DROP TABLE persons
ALTER TABLE persons_temp RENAME TO persons
```

I wanted to test that with `androidx.room:room-testing`, so I created a simple test that just validates the schema:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MigrationTest {

    @get:Rule
    val helper = MigrationTestHelper(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            MyDatabase::class.java.canonicalName,
            FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())

    @Test
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun migrate1To2() {
        // Just let the helper validate the schema changes.
        helper.createDatabase("migration-test", 1)
        helper.runMigrationsAndValidate("migration-test", 2, true, MyDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2)
    }
}
```

However the test fails with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: persons_fts
Expected: FtsTableInfo{name='persons_fts', columns=[name, rowid], options=[content=`persons`]}
Found: FtsTableInfo{name='persons_fts', columns=[name], options=[content=`persons`]}
```

For some reason the FTS table is missing its `rowid` column. But as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Fts4#contentEntity()), triggers are supposed to be removed during the migration so the FTS table should be unaffected. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to resolve this issue while writing the question so I guess I'll post it anyway. By deleting the `rowid` property from my FTS entity, the test passes:

```
@Fts4(contentEntity = Person::class)
@Entity(tableName = "persons_fts")
data class PersonFts(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String)
```

The documentation says the `rowid` property is optional and will still be available in queries even if omitted. However, by defining it, the generated schema is different, it has a `rowid` column which is not present if the property is omitted. I believe that's why the migration test fails. I'm not really sure if this is a bug or not.